# php email form using exchange error

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a form on my local intranet that connects to my exchange server to send an email.

The email is being sent and I am receiving it but after submitting the form I receive a 500 - internal server error on my site.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="formdiv">
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform">
<table width="100" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: left">
    <label for="Subject">Name:</label>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="Message">Text Area:</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea name="Message" id="Message"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" id="SubmitButton" value="Send Message"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the send_form_email.php

```
<?php
ini_set('SMTP', '10.129.129.200');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
$from="form@UKintranet.com";
$email="damon.page@harting.com";
$subject=$_POST['Subject'];
$message=$_POST['Message'];
mail ( $email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
?>
```

Comment: Check the logs or enable display_errors (only if in local) to see the actual error message

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much I added a few things to the PHP which gave me an error message which told me to add the timezone to my code. so the new code looks like so

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
ini_set("error_log", syslog);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('SMTP', '10.129.129.200');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
$from="form@UKintranet.com";
$email="damon.page@harting.com";
$subject=$_POST['Subject'];
$message=$_POST['Message'];
mail ( $email, $subject, $message, "From:".$from);
?>
```